# jQuery- Why assigning a value to a global variable doesn't work inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a slider with 2 buttons to make the number go higher/lower. Here's [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2q1rg56z/3/)

This works:

```
    var update_num;
    $('.plus').on('click', function() {
         update_num = $('output').text()*1;    
       if (update_num < 100) {
            $('output').text(update_num + 1);
        } else {
            $('output').text(100);
        }
        });

    $('.minus').on('click', function() {
        update_num = $('output').text()*1;          
        if (update_num > 0) {
            $('output').text(update_num - 1);
        } else {
            $('output').text(0);
        }
    });
```

But this doesn't work:

```
    var update_num = $('output').text()*1;
    $('.plus').on('click', function() {
         if (update_num < 100) {
            $('output').text(update_num + 1);
        } else {
            $('output').text(100);
        }
        });

    $('.minus').on('click', function() {
        if (update_num > 0) {
            $('output').text(update_num - 1);
        } else {
            $('output').text(0);
        }
    });
```

Why is it so, since var update_num is global and all other functions should be able to read it? And what should be the best way to make this code DRY?

Comment: When your global variable update_num is run, does $('output') exist?  And if so, update_num is never updated in your callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the value of *update_num* is set only once in the second code snippet. For example if its 2. Then every time the minus button is clicked, the value is (2-1) and same way (2+1) when plus button is clicked. The value of *update_num* should change with every button click.

Your question says why assigning value to global variable doesnt work. But in the second code assignment is never done on button click.
Try this:

```
var update_num = $('output').text()*1;
$('.plus').on('click', function() {
     if (update_num < 100) {
        $('output').text(++update_num);
    } else {
        $('output').text(100);
    }
    });

$('.minus').on('click', function() {
    if (update_num > 0) {
        $('output').text(--update_num);
    } else {
        $('output').text(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: That was it! I was wondering why it only updated once and stopped, ++/-- was the answer. Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember one thing, global variable are dangerous.
Say you have initially `update_num` as 34. So on `$('.plus').on('click', function()` the value becomes 35. But if you again click, the update_num will not change as it is set only once at  `var update_num = $('output').text()*1;` There is no two way binding which means that if you change `$('output').text()*1;` the value of `update_num` will also change
You can search google and learn more about the `two way binding` or the `Observable Javascript Pattern`.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware that global variable should be avoided to keep the global space clean. My main concern was to figure out global variable then wrap the whole part inside a function (which I did and jsfiddle is updated accordingly). I will look up two way binding/js pattern more in depth, thanks for your help!